# how to apply a function on elements of ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following XAML

```
<ListBox Name="feedListBox" Height="468" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectionChanged="feedListBox_SelectionChanged"  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyData}}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                  <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="24" Name="feedTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Text="{Binding Title.Text, Path=Arabic , Converter={StaticResource RssTextTrimmer}}"  />
                  <TextBlock Name="feedSummary" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Summary.Text, Converter={StaticResource RssTextTrimmer}}"  />
                  <TextBlock Name="feedPubDate" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" Margin="12,0,0,10" Text="{Binding PublishDate.DateTime}"  />
              </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now I have this object

```
crAr = new Arabic.Controls.ArabicShape();
```

I want to apply the DisplayArabic method on every element of the XAML like this:

```
///// FeedTitle TextBlock
{TextBlock ELEMENT content} = crAr.DisplayArabic( {TextBlock ELEMENT content} );

///// FeedSummary TextBlock
{TextBlock ELEMENT content} = crAr.DisplayArabic( {TextBlock ELEMENT content} );

///// FeedPubDate TextBlock
{TextBlock ELEMENT content} = crAr.DisplayArabic( {TextBlock ELEMENT content} );
```

How could this be written in C# ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [How to: Bind to a Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348824.aspx).